# Creating a symlink gives cannot overwrite directory error

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a Django app with a postgresql backend. Postgresql creates temporary files every now and then - this can be a killer if disk space is critical (as is my case).

One way to alleviate the problem is to create a symlink to some other storage location where disk space isn't a bottleneck. In my case, postgresql stores temporary files at `/$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`. I have a big SSD mounted at `/mnt`, so I want the temp files to reside there instead. The following ought to take care of this:

```
ln -sTf /mnt/pgsql_tmp $PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp
chown -R postgres /mnt/pgsql_tmp #ensuring user 'postgres' has the right perms
chmod o+x /mnt
```

Before I do this in production, I decided to test this out locally. I created `/mnt` and `/pgsql_tmp` on my desktop, and then tried `ln -sTf /home/hassan/Desktop/mnt/pgsql_tmp /home/hassan/Desktop/pgsql_tmp`.

But this ends up giving me `ln: ‘/home/hassan/Desktop/pgsql_tmp’: cannot overwrite directory`. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Being a neophyte, I'm really trying to wrap my head around how this works.

Comment: I think you should consider the meaning of the `T` and `f` flags of `ln`, and then I think you should not do this at all. First, it's intransparent. Second, databases love to have things under control and it's even possible that the system will not open such a file because `open()` calls can be told to treat symbolic links as errors. The reason is that symbolic links can point pretty much anywhere. Yor first choice should be to change the configuration of your database.

Comment: Well this kind of a configuration is standard practice in postgresql universe: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Storage-location-of-temporary-files-tp1909870p1909878.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It reads "I believe it's accepted practice", which is somewhat different from "it's standard practice". But surely it's evidence that it worked at least in some configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to delete `~/pgsql_tmp`, and let the ln command create it.

First note that [LN](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) doesn't link two objects; it creates a link to a target with a specific name from a place.

`ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`

When you create a link with `ln`, the NAME argument should indicate an object that does not yet exist, and it will be created as the result of the command. In your case you already created it (`~/pgsql_tmp`) as a directory.

Usually, You can use the `-f` switch to force deletion of anything already overlaping the NAME's path, but in your case you specified `-T` which means that you want to create the link as a File, not as a Directory. So when `-f` goes to overwrite the object at NAME, its trying to overwrite a directory with a file.

So, you can either create the link as a directory and use -f, or you can delete the object that overlaps NAME, and then create your link. The later is the best option.

```
#create a test target with a file, but without an object at lnname
~/tmp$ mkdir lntarget
~/tmp$ touch lntarget/contentfile1
~/tmp$ ln -sTf lntarget lnname
~/tmp$ ls ./lnname
contentfile1
```

Comment: I suppose deleting `/pgsql_tmp` and letting the `ln` command create it was the main ingredient I'm missing. Tell me something. My real scenario is that postgresql logs are saved in `/$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`, whereas I want them to all reside in `/mnt/pgsql_tmp`. So is this what I need to do: first **delete** the folder `pgsql_tmp` within `/$PGDATA/base/`. Create a folder called `/pgsql_tmp` within `mnt`, and then run `ln -s /mnt/pgsql_tmp /$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp`. Correct?

Comment: yes, though you would probably move the data from `/$PGDATA/base/` to `mnt/pgsql_tmp` rather than deleting it in most cases.

Comment: `you can either create the link as a directory and use -f` I see no way to make `ln` replace directory with symlink, other than by removing directory before running `ln`. What does "create the link as a directory" mean anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but want to add more details.

As per your question your 
Source = "/$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp"
Destination = "/mnt/pgsql_tmp"

So at destination you don't need to mention "pgsql_tmp", when you run "ln -sf" it will create new "pgsql_tmp" or if it already exist then it will simply link it to source. So your command should be following.

> ln -sf  /$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp /mnt/

Above mentioned case is when you want to have destination link as of same name as source like "pgsql_tmp" is on source and it will be same on destination. If destination directory name is different then use the switch T like below.

> ln -sfT  /$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp /mnt/new_dir